# Best way to return 1 of a few different strings

Tags: c++

I have a design question. I'm writing a function in c++ that checks how a user installed my code, so either "app store", "web", "dvd". What is the best way to encode these? I imagine I don't literally want to return the strings, so should I use a #define for the three options and make them 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, or should I use an enum? Or some other option?

Answer (score 2):

Re

> **”** , so should I use a #define for the three options

**No.**

Only use macros as a last resort.

You can use an `enum`, and that's far better than stringly typed code.